# How we can set the direction to RTL in languages changes of DSpace digital repository

Tags: css, right-to-left, multilingual, dspace

How can we set the direction to RTL in languages change of DSpace digital repository? the second language in our implementation is an RTL language like Persian. rtl.css stylesheet was provided.
We need a solution to assign rtl.css in selecting multiple languages
Sincerely;

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with a combination of HTML / page level text direction setting, and CSS to switch placement of some page elements.

Here is what I had managed to accomplish while trying some Arabic language display, I think Persian will be very similar? (you might just have to change the 'ar' locale to 'fa', etc.)
This example was tested in Mirage2, but the concepts can apply elsewhere.

In my new theme, I overwrote `page-structure.xsl`, and I set the whole page document 'dir' attribute to 'rtl' if I detect a locale that wants in (in this case, Arabic)

```
   <!-- switch to rtl if arabic locale -->
   <xsl:variable name="active-locale" select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='page'][@qualifier='currentLocale']"/>
   <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$active-locale='ar'">
                   <script><xsl:text>document.documentElement.setAttribute('dir','rtl');</xsl:text></script>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
                   <script><xsl:text>document.documentElement.setAttribute('dir','ltr');</xsl:text></script>       
           </xsl:otherwise>        
   </xsl:if>
```

That should be enough to sort out the text in the page...

I also made use of a custom bootstrap rtl theme (https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) to apply CSS (it's probably similar to the CSS you have?) transformations to flip placement of eg. menu bars or containers to make the page more readable in RTL
To do this, i included the minified CSS in my theme's `style` folder along with other CSS and added this stylesheet reference to my theme's `page-structure.xsl`:

```
<!-- Add Bootstrap 3 RTL support if Arabic locale detected -->
    <xsl:if test="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='page'][@qualifier='currentLocale']='ar'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{concat($theme-path, 'styles/bootstrap-rtl.min.css')}"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

You can use the '.flip' class (as documented on the github page for bootstrap-rtl) to be more specific about flipping certain elements (you'd edit various other XMLUI templates to get those classes in there)... my expertise in how things *should* look for RTL reading is lacking so I haven't customised individual elements.

Hope this helps! If you're getting stuck with XMLUI / Mirage2 customisation, when it comes to actually applying these changes, you can read https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Mirage+2+Configuration+and+Customization to give some more background.